# Handlebars #each block doesn't work - The "this" scope is still the global scope

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I had a problem with #each block not looping anything.

I thought it's a problem with my app, so I tried to recreate the bug in CopePen and I got the same problem.

Here's the pen: https://codepen.io/hrsetyono/pen/YzZoRgg?editors=1111

It's a very simple example with these HTML:

```html
<main></main>

<div id="template-list" style="display:none;">
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Job</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {{#each people }}
      <tr>
        <td>
          <strong>{{ name }}</strong>
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ job }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {{/each }}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Then the JS:

```js
let data = {
  title: 'Employee List',
  people: [
    { name: 'John', job: 'Gardener' },
    { name: 'Sarah', job: 'Sales' }
  ]
};

let rawTemplate = document.querySelector( '#template-list' ).innerHTML;
let $target = document.querySelector( 'main' );

let template = Handlebars.compile( rawTemplate );
let html = template( data );
$target.innerHTML = html;
```

The result is empty table because the #each loop doesn't properly set the scope.

Comment: I would've thought it was `each people` ... since `{{title}}` is clearly `data.title` ... so wouldn't you just use `{{#each people}}` ?

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX, sorry I have fixed the Pen, even with `each people`, it still won't output anything. I added the `data.title` to see whether the Handlebars work

Comment: @JaromandaX never mind, found out that the template has to be inside `<script>` tag

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Handlebars template has to be inside `<script>` like this:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  ...
</script>
```

Now everything works

Comment: By the way, you can also do `{{#people }} ...... {{/people}}` instead of `{{#each people}} ...... {{/each}}`